# jQuery UI: Filter selectable dates on datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to filter the selectable dates on a datepicker. I basically need to filter by work days - i.e. make holidays and weekends not selectable.

I know you can specify dates using a function in the beforeShowDate: and you can also use $.datepicker.noWeekends.

Question is: can you do both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$.datepicker.noWeekends is a pretty simple bit of code:

```
function (date) { 
    var day = date.getDay(); 
    return [day > 0 && day < 6, ""]; 
}
```

Since you're going to have to write up the function for holidays, you can just include this logic in that function too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the opposite and have the input what dates are selectable and leave all the rest filtered out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

i.e. If you only want the user to be able to select Mondays you would add something like:

```
onlyMondays: function(date){
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day == 1), ""]
}
```